# Gerar array com valores aleatórios em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quero gerar um array com 10 posições tipo: `var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

Mas queria que o computador escolhesse 10 números de -9 a 9, para colocar dentro desse array.

Answer (score 10):

Pode-se usar a função da MDN [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) para gerar números randômicos com intervalo:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

**Exemplo**

```js
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

let array = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
  array.push(getRandom(-9,9));
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Onde `floor` é aplicado para obter um inteiro.

Answer (score -2):

para um código mais legível, você pode usar a solução acima, mas se você quiser um código menor, você pode usar esse aqui

```js
// [...Array(10)] gera um array com 10 undefineds
// .map() vai preencher todos os elementos do array de acordo com uma função
// ()=>Math.random()*18-9   é a função que retorna um número aleatório entre -9 e 9 (se você quiser inteiros use ()=>Math.floor(Math.random()*19-9))
var array = [...Array(10)].map(()=>Math.random()*18-9);

console.log(array);
```